# Counter-intuitive performance issue using Samsung T5 SSD on M2 pro Macmini

Tags: mac, usb, ssd, performance, usb-hub

M2pro 16gb Mac Mini, OSX 13.2.1

BenQ PD32220u Monitor (with USB interfaces)

Samsung T5 SSD 2TB (USB 3.1 gen2)

I've recently upgraded my workstation, have been using a T5 External drive for some time at expected (near max) R/W speeds (~475-500MBS) previously on imac 2013.

Now I am experiencing variable performance depending on the interface and configuration I use in my new setup - most perplexing I am seeing **faster R/W speeds when the drive is connected to USB hub on my monitor, than when connected directly to the macmini**. Summary of my configurations and the Black Magic Disk results below. I am using Samsung supplied cables in all cases. Respective results are consistent across multiple cycles.

[Connection configuration | Write Speed,Read Speed MBs]

T5 --> BenQ Monitor (USB C to USB A) --> Macmini (USB C Thunderbolt 3)
[image]

T5 --> Macmini (USB C to USB A)
[image: T5 --> Macmini (USB C to USB A)]

T5 --> Macmini (USB C to USB C)
[image]

**Why does a direct connection to the macmini (using the same supplied cables) result in degraded performance?** Unfortunately leaving the drive connected to the monitor isn't practical, as it disconnects whenever the monitor sleeps.

Comment: All your devices seem to support USB C, so where are you using USB A? I would think that  Thunderbolt is faster than USB C, so perhaps does a better job.

Comment: @harrymc Agreed Using USB C would typically be the go to, which is why I noticed the discrepancy, because that was my first configuration. Testing disk speed showed that I was getting worse results than what I expected. The ssd comes with both USB C to USB C and USB C to USB A cables. I started experimenting and found that connecting using USB A yielded different results, as demonstrated above. The confounding issue is why the performance is worse when directly connected, regardless of the interface.

Comment: My opinion is that  Thunderbolt is responsible for the speed improvement, and the monitor does a good job as a dock.